# #550 5.6.0 M2MCVT.StorageError; storage error in content conversion ##

Tags: exchange, exchange-2007, ndr

We are getting this error on one user's computer, running Windows 7 and Outlook 2007 in a domain environment.  Exchange Server is 2007.

It only happens occasionally for random email addresses, internally and externally.  Sometimes sending images and sometimes not it seems.

Any ideas on how to resolve this?

I have done my reading around and seen problems related to sending vCards and BES.  We are not sending vCards or digitally signing emails, or sending from Blackberry handsets in this case.

An example NDR is below:

```
_____________________________________________
From: Microsoft Exchange 
Sent: 17 August 2010 09:18
To: Mr Sender
Subject: Undeliverable: RE: booking
Delivery has failed to these recipients or distribution lists:

Mr Recipient <mailto:Mr.Recipient@email.com> 
The e-mail system had a problem processing this message. Microsoft Exchange will not try to redeliver this message for you. Please provide the following diagnostic text to your system administrator.
 _____  
Sent by Microsoft Exchange Server 2007 

Diagnostic information for administrators:

Generating server: exchsvr.domain.local

Mr.Recipient@email.com
#550 5.6.0 M2MCVT.StorageError; storage error in content conversion ##

Original message headers:

Received: from exchsvr.domain.local ([192.168.0.1]) by exchsvr.domain.local
 ([192.168.0.1]) with mapi; Tue, 17 Aug 2010 09:17:39 +0100
Content-Type: application/ms-tnef; name="winmail.dat"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
From: Mr Sender <Mr.Sender@domain.com>
To: Mr Recipient <Mr.Recipient@email.com>
Date: Tue, 17 Aug 2010 09:17:38 +0100
Subject: RE: booking
Thread-Topic: booking
Thread-Index: Acs7kjK27G45MtsWStyjlgX8C2bAsAABCO8YAJNQgYAAAD3wYA==
Message-ID: <18BA3EFCD95BA44AA359B7358A909BE211035339B4@synexch01.domain.local>
References: <F1A0F7931758C047869ACB087522B76590A8931D7D@s-dor001-mx01.blah.net>
 <F1A0F7931758C047869ACB087522B76590A8F60B68@s-dor001-mx01.blah.net>
In-Reply-To: <F1A0F7931758C047869ACB087522B76590A8F60B68@s-dor001-mx01.blah.net>
Accept-Language: en-US, en-GB
Content-Language: en-US
X-MS-Has-Attach: yes
X-MS-TNEF-Correlator: <18BA3EFCD95BA44AA359B7358A909BE211035339B4@exchsvr.domain.local>
MIME-Version: 1.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen this same error on our system.  We're WinXP, Outlook 2007, Exchange 2007.

We have a third-party application that creates calendar events that are placed onto the local user's Outlook calendar using the local MAPI profile.  That portion works fine.  But if there are any other users identified for that calendar event, Outlook wants to send them an invite.  This causes the message to then go through Exchange, and we get the exact same NDA you have.

After much work back and forth with the third-party vendor, we have identified formatting issues (with the headers, I believe) in the message (calendar event) they are creating.  We did not have these issues until we moved from Exchange 2003 to Exchange 2007, so it is safe to say that Exchange 2007 requires a much stricter adherence to the RFC standards.

One way of validating this, aside from the NDA, is to attempt to open the calendar item (assuming yours is a calendar item, too) while you are logged into Outlook Web Access.  I found that OWA reports a problem immediately with that item.  This was also the way we were able to identify what Exchange/OWA had a problem with in particular (which header item).

Hope that helps!

Comment: BES was being used, although not for sending the actual messages.  After upgrading BES to the latest version and installing available SP's to Exchange, all working fine - so I think you were on the right lines about third-party software which prompted me to head off in the right direction in the end.

Comment: I can report this error in the scenario of GpgOL in Outlook 2010, when taking an email that I'd previously digitally signed and sent to recipient A, and then trying to forward to recipient B.

Answer (score 1):

I am facing this issue and I sorted out this issue with the help of these steps.

If you have any attachments in email, than remove those attachments and check either there is an issue in any attached file by removing one by one.

I have an issue in PDF file, I opened that file and than save as that file again at my desktop and than attach in the email, now jpg and pdf file both successfully sent to internet domains.

Regards,
Nausherwan Moiz